# Swift: How to not load AppDelegate during Tests

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have an OS X application which on startup loads some data from a server and pushes notifications to the `NSUserNotificationCenter`.
Now I have the problem that this also happens during my unit tests. I found no way yet to prevent this. Of course I could stub the HTTP loads. But in some cases I want to test the loading and then the notifications get sent anyway.

What I'm trying to do is to make the test runs not load the `AppDelegate` but a fake one that I'm only using for tests. I found several examples [1] on how to do that with `UIApplicationMain`, where you can pass a specific AppDelegate class name. The same is not possible with `NSApplicationMain` [2].

What I've tried is the following:

Removed `@NSApplicationMain` from `AppDelegate.swift`, then added a `main.swift` with the following content:

```
class FakeAppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
}

NSApplication.sharedApplication()
NSApp.delegate = FakeAppDelegate()
NSApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv)
```

This code runs before tests but has no effect at all.

I might have to say: My AppDelegate is almost empty. To handle the MainMenu.xib stuff I made a separate view controller which does the actual loading and notification stuff in `awakeFromNib`.

[1] http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/prevent-unit-tests-from-loading-app-delegate-in-swift/

[2] https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSApplicationMain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of trying and failing I found an answer on the [Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/20001#20001):

> The problem was that my main.swift file was initializing my AppDelegate before NSApplication had been initialized. The Apple documentation makes it clear that lots of other Cocoa classes rely on NSApplication to be up and running when they are initialized. Apparently, NSObject and NSWindow are two of them.

So my final and working code in `main.swift` looks like this:

```
private func isTestRun() -> Bool {
    return NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil
}

private func runApplication(
    application: NSApplication = NSApplication.sharedApplication(),
    delegate: NSObject.Type?   = nil,
    bundle: NSBundle?          = nil,
    nibName: String            = "MainMenu") {

    var topLevelObjects: NSArray?

    // Actual initialization of the delegate is deferred until here:
    application.delegate = delegate?.init() as? NSApplicationDelegate

    guard bundle != nil else {
        application.run()
        return
    }

    if bundle!.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: application, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects ) {
        application.run()
    } else {
        print("An error was encountered while starting the application.")
    }
}

if isTestRun() {
    let mockDelegateClass = NSClassFromString("MockAppDelegate") as? NSObject.Type
    runApplication(delegate: mockDelegateClass)
} else {
    runApplication(delegate: AppDelegate.self, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
}
```

So the actual problem before was that the Nib was being loaded during tests. This solution prevents this. It just loads the application with a mocked application delegate whenever it detects a test run (By looking for the `XCTest` class).

I'm sure I will have to tweak this a bit more. Especially when a start with UI Testing. But for the moment it works.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot convert value of type 'AppDelegate.Type' to expected argument type 'NSApplication'`

Answer (score 4):

Just an update on the previous accept answer, this is my `main.swift`:

```
private func isTestRun() -> Bool {
    return NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") != nil
}

if isTestRun() {
    // This skips setting up the app delegate
    NSApplication.shared.run()
} else {
    // For some magical reason, the AppDelegate is setup when
    // initialized this way
    _ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
}
```

A bit more compact! I'm using Swift 4.1 and XCode 9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I was running Test Cases. Test cases crashes at AppDelegate. So, I tried this solution which worked nicely. I hope it would work for you.

Solution:-

Step 1: Create a main.swift file

Step 2: Add this few line of code in main.swift file.

```
import UIKit

private func delegateClassName() -> String? {
    let className = NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") == nil ? NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self) : NSStringFromClass(TestingAppDelegate.self)
    return className
}

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, delegateClassName())
```

Step 3: Create a TestingAppDelegate.swift file

Step 4: Add this one line of code

```
class TestingAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
}
```

Step 5: Remove @UIApplicationMain from top of AppDelegate.swift file

## Now Run Your Test Cases. It Will Run